# Installing Weblogic 12 on Windows 8 Server - http server won't start

Tags: windows-server-2012, oracle

Apologies in advance for the terrible formatting - I spent more time getting to this point than I did asking my question.

I'm trying to install Weblogic 12 on Windows 8 Server. I've followed the wizards and I can start the admin console and log in and things seem to work right up until I try to start the HTTP server. It fails with the following error:

`weblogic.nodemanager.NMException: Received error message from Node Manager Server: [Server start command for OHS server 'ohs_1' failed due to: [Failed to start the server ohs_1
    Check log file C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\system_components\OHS\ohs_nm.log
    Check log file C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\ohs_1\logs\ohs_1.log]. Please check Node Manager log and/or server 'ohs_1' log for detailed information.]. Please check Node Manager log for details.
    at weblogic.nodemanager.client.NMServerClient.checkResponse(NMServerClient.java:552)
    at weblogic.nodemanager.client.NMServerClient.checkResponse(NMServerClient.java:565)
    at weblogic.nodemanager.client.NMServerClient.start(NMServerClient.java:124)
    at weblogic.nodemanager.client.DefaultSSLClient.start(DefaultSSLClient.java:14)
    at weblogic.nodemanager.mbean.StartRequest.start(StartRequest.java:78)
    at weblogic.nodemanager.mbean.StartRequest.run(StartRequest.java:47)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)`

So that remarkably unhelpful message leads me to `C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\system_components\OHS\ohs_nm.log`

That log contains this:

`[2014-11-07 14:38:15] [INFO] [OHS-4018] [Starting server ohs_1]
[2014-11-07 14:38:15] [INFO] [OHS-0] [Running C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\launch.exe C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\httpd.exe -f C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\instances\ohs_1\httpd.conf]
[2014-11-07 14:38:16] [INFO] [OHS-0] [C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\launch.exe C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\httpd.exe -f C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\instances\ohs_1\httpd.conf: exit status = -1072365566]
[2014-11-07 14:38:16] [INFO] [OHS-4005] [Check the instance log file for more information: C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\ohs_1\logs\ohs_1.log]
[2014-11-07 14:38:16] [SEVERE] [OHS-0] [Failed to start the server ohs_1]
[2014-11-07 14:42:50] [INFO] [OHS-4018] [Starting server ohs_1]
[2014-11-07 14:42:50] [INFO] [OHS-0] [Running C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\launch.exe C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\httpd.exe -f C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\instances\ohs_1\httpd.conf]
[2014-11-07 14:42:51] [INFO] [OHS-0] [C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\launch.exe C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\ohs\bin\httpd.exe -f C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\instances\ohs_1\httpd.conf: exit status = -1072365566]
[2014-11-07 14:42:51] [INFO] [OHS-4005] [Check the instance log file for more information: C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\ohs_1\logs\ohs_1.log]
[2014-11-07 14:42:51] [SEVERE] [OHS-0] [Failed to start the server ohs_1]`

So I checked the instance log file, as suggested, and it's empty. Oracle support so far has been unhelpful. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oracle product logs make my eyes bleed.

Comment: They've always been bad, and now that they're more heavily into Java it's gotten even worse. Who would have thought I'd miss the days of just Googling "ORA-12345"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exit status (in hex, 0xc0150002) typically means that you're missing a dependency for the EXE.

I'd throw [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) at the `httpd.exe` and `launch.exe` to see if you're missing any dependent DLLs. I feel like Visual C++ runtime libraries might be the culprit, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It's unlikely that I'll be able to get permission to run that on the server. Is there another way to check the dependencies?

Comment: You can always copy the file to another machine, dump out the dependencies, then manually walk them on the production server yourself.

Comment: That's probably not an option either (government computers). However, I did try running httpd.exe from the command line and it told me that oraiau.dll was missing, and a little Googling of that lead me to a page that suggests I'm missing Visual C++ runtime components. I'll let you know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092

Comment: I installed the Visual C++ patch from the link above and now the server starts up. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help.